$\int x^3\sqrt{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$ by Substituting $u=x^2+1$
$$\int x^3\sqrt{x^2+1}$$
On substituting $u=x^2+1\implies\mathrm du=2x\mathrm dx$
$$\frac12\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}$$
I was able to get $u$ and $\mathrm du$ but I don’t understand how this simplifies to $u^\frac32 - u^\frac12$. If anyone could explain this, it would be a huge help.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

You have made a mistake of not writing $\mathrm dx$ in the first line and $\mathrm du$ in the last line at the end of the integrand while performing the substitution. It is mandatory to mention the variable whose respect to integration is being done, just like while differentiating a function, it is mandatory to mention the variable whose respect to differentiation is being done. This is denoted by its differential at the end of the integrand, like for $x$, it's $\mathrm dx$. Intuitively, you can think of the differential of a variable as a very, very small(infinitesimal) change in that variable, i.e., close to but never equal to $0$.
As you are changing variables from $x$ to $u$, everything in $x$ needs to be rewritten in terms of $u$ so that we can integrate in terms of the new variable $u$(which is denoted by the differential $\mathrm du$). Hence, using $x^2=u-1$ and $\sqrt{x^2+1}=\sqrt u$,
$$\int x^3\sqrt{x^2+1}\mathrm dx$$
$$=\frac12\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}(2x\mathrm dx)$$
$$=\frac12\int (u-1)\sqrt u\mathrm du$$
$$=\frac12\int u^\frac32-u^\frac12\mathrm du$$
This is the desired integral.
